# when I use the code copy from rosbag tutorials,there some wrong?

Tags: rosbag

[image: Rosanswers logo]

when I use the code copy from the tutorial(http://wiki.ros.org/rosbag/Code%20API),but there are some wrong like this:error: expected primary-expression before ‘const’
foreach(rosbag::MessageInstance const m, view);
error: ‘foreach’ was not declared in this scope
foreach(rosbag::MessageInstance const m, view);
I don't know how to correct,I hope someone can help me ,thank you!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/202155/when--i-use-the-code-copy-from-rosbag-tutorials,there-some-wrong?/) by [cros](https://answers.ros.org/users/21043/cros/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2015-01-31

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

foreach is not a valid keyword in C++; the rosbag tutorials assume that you have foreach defined as BOOST_FOREACH:

```
#include <boost/foreach.hpp>
#define foreach BOOST_FOREACH
```

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2015-01-31

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [cros](https://answers.ros.org/users/21043/cros/) on 2015-01-31**:
thank you ,then can you tell me what's function of 'foreach',

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2015-01-31**:
The [BOOST_FOREACH](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_57_0/doc/html/foreach.html) documentation defines the behavior of BOOST_FOREACH fairly well.